# python XlsxWriter text wrapping and links styling

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I need help with python XlsxWriter. I need to add link styling for external file link columns. But Xlsxwriter doesn't recognize styling for links(its second column) (text: underline, text-color: blue) if I'm adding the text wrapping for another columns(in this example first column).

Here is my example:

```
# _*_ coding: utf-8
import xlsxwriter

wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('/home/mtw/Downloads/my_export.xlsx')

format = wb.add_format()
format.set_text_wrap()

sheet = wb.add_worksheet(name='export_object1')
sheet.write_row('A1', [
    u'Its\na bum\nwrap',
    'external:resignation_letter.docx',
], format)
wb.close()
```

So I need to tell the XlsxWriter that he can recognize and text wrapping and styling for links.

Microsoft office: 2007.

xlsxwriter latest version.

Thx.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Links in Excel have cell formatting (generally blue text and an underline) like any other formatted text.

If no other formatting is specified for links in XlsxWriter the module adds a default (blue underline) format, like Excel does when you enter a url. This is explained in the [`write_url()`](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/worksheet.html#worksheet-write-url) docs.

However, if the user specifies a format for a cell with a link (like the text_wrap format in your example) then it overrides the default format.

So if you want blue underline plus text wrap format for urls you will have to specify it directly:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('my_export.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(name='export_object1')

link_format = workbook.add_format({'color': 'blue', 
                                   'underline': True, 
                                   'text_wrap': True})

text_format = workbook.add_format({'text_wrap': True})

worksheet.write('A1', 'Its\na bum\nwrap',           text_format)
worksheet.write('B1', 'http://stackoverflow.com/',  link_format)

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but as I understood, I can not to use one row for writing data as in my example (`sheet.write_row`) and pass in method just a list? The trouble in that I have a lot of data, which I'm handling and writing, and it's will be not comfortable to write each column with `sheet.write`.

Comment: it would be great if user could to specify in string which needs to be wrapped something like a `worksheet.write_row('A1', ['text_wrap: Its\na bum\nwrap', 'external:resignation_letter.docx'])`