# xlsxwriter format specific cell

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

I've seen many pages on here to format the width of an entire column, but is there a way to format an individual cell width? My issue is that I'm creating a sheet that has a "header" more or less, several rows where each column is a different length because they're been mergered to include unique information. Below this section will be a standard dataframe, which the entire column's width will need to be formatted to the data. But for the first five rows I need to specify unique width values. Is this possible?

Comment: may be this would help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51631138/writing-text-wrapped-excel-files-using-python-solved

Comment: You want to format the width of columns in the first 5 rows different from those in the following rows? How should that be possible in _one table_? You can merge columns in excel .. you might be able to hack around with that - but it makes it quite complicated

Comment: I think the OP means wrapping up the texts. Surely width changing should not be possible for diff rows in same column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

xlswriter has a format feature saying how to change the properties of the spreadsheet cell: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html

```
import xlsxwriter

# Create a workbook and add a worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Expenses01.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

cell_format = workbook.add_format()
cell_format.set_bold()
cell_format.set_font_color('red')
```

There are properties to do everything including change the width of the cell.